# .add() in java AWT not working after actionPerformed

Tags: java, button, awt

I am fairly new to coding and have encountered this issue within my code.
I create a button using the Java AWT import. I then check for a response using a while loop and wish to create another button after, however .add() seems to no longer function.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Main1
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       Frame f = new Frame();
       f.setSize(500, 500);
       f.setVisible(true);
       ButtonPanel bp = new ButtonPanel(f);
       
       bp.x = null;
       while (bp.x == null)
       {
       }
       System.out.println(bp.x);
       
       //THE ISSUE- THIS WILL NOT APPEAR AFTER BUTTON PRESS
       f.add("South", new Button("REEE"));
    }
}
```

```
class ButtonPanel extends Panel implements ActionListener
{
    volatile String x;
    public ButtonPanel(Frame f)
    {
        Button b = new Button("Hi");
        b.addActionListener(this);
        f.add("North", b);
    }
    
    
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        x = e.getActionCommand();
    }
}
```

I have been trying solutions for this for the last day or so and nothing seems to be working. I've seen in other posts people have said to use Wait/Notify however I am not too sure how those work and I would like to know explicitly what is going wrong in my program (though I am still open to using Wait/Notify in my solution).

Any help would be appreciated, thank you very much

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, I was testing something, meant to remove it for this here

Comment: Don't use a `while` loop to "stop" code execution like this.  Instead, use a callback (observer)

Comment: Strong suggestion: don't use AWT. There are two generations of gui frameworks after AWT: Swing and JavaFX. If you want to learn something new, try javafx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like nothing is happening because the buttons are being added below the bottom of the window. You should consider using a layout manager to solve this issue.

However, in the meantime the simple solution is to move this line `f.add("South", new Button("REEE"));` inside the action event and to make use of `Frame.pack();`:

```
public class Main1
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       Frame f = new Frame();
       //set minimums rather than a fixed size
       f.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
       f.setVisible(true);
       CustomButton b = new CustomButton(f);

       //Add this line to update/size/show the UI
       f.pack();
       
       //Don't place any more code inside the main method. Future events should be triggered by interacting with the UI/buttons
    }
}
```

Then for the button we don't need to extend Panel, we can do something like this:

```
class CustomButton implements ActionListener
{
    Frame parentFrame;
    public CustomButton(Frame f)
    {
        parentFrame = f;
        Button b = new Button("Hi");
        b.addActionListener(this);
        f.add("North", b);
    }
    
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        //Add button here instead of the main class
        parentFrame.add("South", new Button("REEE"));
        //The buttons are being added below the bottom of your window, this will force them to be shown.
        //Using a layout manager will solve this ploblem and you will not need to do this:
        parentFrame.pack();
    }
}
```

Note: clicking on the "Hi" button multiple times will have interesting results of the "REEE" buttons overlapping or doing odd things if you resize the window.

Comment: OHHHH, I am such an idiot sometimes, I had no clue it would be created outside the frame, thank you

Comment: Rather then using `pack`, which may affect the size of the window if the user changes it, better to revalidate the container containing the buttons

Answer (score 1):

So, they're a number of issues at play here.

The first is the fact that layout managers are generally lazy.  This means that you can add and/or remove a number of components quickly and then do a single layout and paint pass.

To do this, you need to `revalidate` the `Container` which was updated.

Next, AWT (and Swing by extension) is based on Model-View-Controller concept, one aspect of this is the "observer pattern".  This is basically a callback concept that allows you to be notified when something of interest happens.

`Button` makes use of an `ActionListener` to generate events when the button is "actioned".  This is the "observer pattern" in action.

Why is this important?  You really want to think about what information is needed to be passed where and who's actually responsible for doing what.

For example, is it really the `ButtonPanel`'s responsibility to update the frame? Is giving `ButtonPanel` unfettered control over the frame really a good idea?

Instead, `ButtonPanel` "should" be providing some kind of notification when some action has occurred and then any interested parties should be able to do what ever they need to.

As a "basic" example...

```
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Panel;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.EventListener;
import javax.swing.event.EventListenerList;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Test();
            }
        });
    }

    public Test() {
        Frame f = new Frame();
        f.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        f.pack();

        ButtonPanel bp = new ButtonPanel(f);
        bp.addObsever(new Observer() {
            @Override
            public void hiWasPerformed() {
                f.add("South", new Button("REEE"));
                f.revalidate();
            }
        });

        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public interface Observer extends EventListener {
        public void hiWasPerformed();
    }


    class ButtonPanel extends Panel  {

        private EventListenerList eventListener = new EventListenerList();

        public ButtonPanel(Frame f) {
            Button b = new Button("Hi");
            b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    Observer[] listeners = eventListener.getListeners(Observer.class);
                    for (Observer observer : listeners) {
                        observer.hiWasPerformed();
                    }
                }
            });
            f.add("North", b);
        }

        public void addObsever(Observer observer) {
            eventListener.add(Observer.class, observer);
        }

        public void removeObsever(Observer observer) {
            eventListener.remove(Observer.class, observer);
        }
    }
}
```